Help with understanding a rigid geometry proof
I am trying to read Coleman's paper "$p$-adic Banach Spaces and Families of Modular Forms". In Proposition A5.5, he considers a quasi-finite morphism $f:Z\to Y=\mathbb{B}^1_K$ where $Z$ is a one-dimensional affinoid over $K = \mathbb{C}_p$ or a complete discretely valued subfield, and he wants to show that for each $k\geq 0$, the set $Y_k := \{x\in Y\mid \deg(f^{-1}(x))\geq k\}$ is an affinoid subdomain of $Y$, where by degree he means the dimension of the ring of functions of the fibre over the residue field at the point.
To this end, he proves that image of an irreducible affinoid under a non-constant morphism to $\mathbb{B}^1_K$ is an affinoid subdomain, and then constructs a subdomain $Z_k$ of $Z$ such that $f(Z_k) = Y_k$. The construction of $Z_k$ is as follows:

I understand that away from all the hyperdiagonals, we get points which look like $k$-tuples of distinct points of $Z$ which map to the same point in $Y$, hence the degree of the fibre above this point will be atleast $k$. But I don't see how does one get that the image of $Z_k$ is exactly $Y_k$.

I find this argument a bit difficult to follow (how does he deal with points of multiplicity $>1$?). Here is an alternative proof using formal models.
Since $Y$ is a smooth rigid-analytic curve, the quasi-finite morphism $f\colon Z\to Y$ is flat. Therefore (by Raynaud-Gruson, Bosch-Luetkebohmert) there exists a formal model $f\colon \mathfrak{Z}\to\mathfrak{Y}$ which is flat and (hence) quasi-finite.
Looking at the map on special fiber $f_0\colon \mathfrak{Z}_0\to \mathfrak{Y}_0$, by the analogous result for varieties, we find that the set of points of $\mathfrak{Y}_0$ with fiber of length at least $k$ is an open subset $\mathfrak{U} \subseteq |\mathfrak{Y}_0| = |\mathfrak{Y}|$.
Let $U\subseteq Y$ be the preimage of $\mathfrak{U}$ under the specialization map $|Y|\to |\mathfrak{Y}|$. This is a quasi-compact open subset, and since $Y$ is an affinoid curve, $U$ is affinoid.
To finish, we show that $U = Y_k$. This means showing that for every (classical) point $y\in Y$ with specialization $y_0 \in \mathfrak{Y}_0$, the length of the fiber of $Z\to Y$ above $y$ equals the length of the fiber of $\mathfrak{Z}_0\to\mathfrak{Y}_0$ above $y_0$.
Recalling the definition of the specialization map, the point $y$ corresponds to a map of formal schemes ${\rm Spf}(\mathcal{O}_L)\to \mathfrak{Y}$ where $L = \kappa(y)$ is a finite extension of the ground field $K$, and the point $y_0$ is the image of the closed point of ${\rm Spf}(\mathcal{O}_L)$.
Pulling back the morphism $f\colon \mathfrak{Z}\to\mathfrak{Y}$ to ${\rm Spf}(\mathcal{O}_L)$, we obtain a finite (!) flat morphism $\mathcal{O}_L\to A$. Therefore the dimensions of $A\otimes L$ and $A\otimes \ell$ (where $\ell$ is the residue field of $\mathcal{O}_L$) are equal.

Thanks for the answer! I am a bit new to rigid geometry, so I haven't learnt how to work with formal models yet. In Coleman's argument I think the points of higher multiplicity are handled with the parts of the irreducible components of $X_k$ which do intersect with the hyperdiagonals. I think that one can somehow "approach" points whose fibres have higher multiplicity using points with reduced fibres but I have no idea how to formalize this idea.
I will revisit your answer after reading about formal models.

I might be mistaken, but isn't the set of points with fibre of length atmost $k$ open for varieties?

Fiber length should be lower semicontinuous for flat quasi-finite maps. To see this, you can reduce to the case of base being a dvr, and apply Zariski's main theorem to compactify the map to a finite flat map.

(In contrast, for a finite, not necessarily flat map, fiber length is upper semicontinuous.)
